# How do I apply a light/dark mask to a mesh?

Tags: texturing, materials, image

I'm not sure if this is something I should be doing in Photoshop or in Blender, but I have a file that looks like this:
[image: texture map]
It is supposed to darken or lighten the underlying color to create shading. I know how to apply transparency and normal masks, but I can't find an option for this one, and I haven't had any luck googling for it.

Comment: Do the different colors represent different shaders?

Comment: I'm not totally sure as my knowledge of terminology is poor, but from what I can tell the green is shading. The purple I would expect to be shading as well, I'm not sure why it is a different colour though. Sorry if I'm not being clear, I was hoping that this would be a common type of mask.

Comment: A shader is simply something that tells the render engine how a surface interacts with light, so I am not quite sure what you mean by "the green is shading".  Where did you get this map?

Comment: It's from a Final Fantasy XIV model. The armour textures from this game appear to be comprised of a text file which dictates the colour selection for certain areas of the mesh, a normal map, and then this file which is titled EQUIPMENTNAME_m.tex.png.
the .tex is the original extension, and it has been converted into a png.

I can recreate the texture that shows up in game by making a very basic colour layer, which is ideally supposed to be affected by the normal layer and then this shading layer. My understanding is that this file is meant to dictate the shading of the colour layer under it.

Comment: I have a feeling you're talking about Ambient Occlusion? Are you? :P https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion http://www.bitmanagement.com/images/press/shading.large.jpg . If so are your textures painted onto a UV Unwrapped mesh already in blender? :)

Comment: That could be several masks packed into one.  It looks like AO might be stored in the alpha channel.  Not sure what the rest is.  Engines tend to use custom shaders.  Here's a guide on how Dota_2 does things.  http://media.steampowered.com/apps/dota2/workshop/Dota2ShaderMaskGuide.pdf  Maybe there is similar docs for FF XIV.  The color looks like a translucency mask to me but I'm guessing. :)

Comment: Sorry for not making much sense. Basically, there is no texture included. I have made a file with just flat colours that this file is supposed to create shading / detail on. I think FFXIV does it this way to simplify recolours of armor since most equipment in the game can be dyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to understand what you are describing. I would have to assume you are using Cycles, and that you already have a mesh that is UV unwrapped to match the layout of this image.

If the above is true, you would "apply a light /dark mask"  by using a mix node set to overlay mode. You would plug your underlying surface into the top of the mix node, and plug this image into the bottom of the mix node. Overlay ensures it will lighten or darken as appropriate to your image. You would then increase the factor to get a level of mixture that you desired.

Hope that helps.